# My apps theme changes in the preview but not in the emulator

Tags: java, android

Whenever i try to change my apps theme, it changes in the preview ,but always stays the same in the emulator. Why is this?

Here is my style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Did you try a Project> Clean before executing?

Comment: @Mandroid1.0 Yes but I didn't work

Comment: check your res folder make sure you put it in the `style.xml` not with extesion `-21` etc.